# Using a stored procedure to populate a column in a ViewTable according to the ID of an another column in the same ViewTable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a view with a column `TeamName` and I want to add to this view another column `Score`.

This column `Score` has to sum all the points of the team in an other table.

Here is the stored procdure I wrote that gets the sum for the total score for the 'AWAY and HOME':

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetScoreForATeam
    @teamId INT,
    @ch_Id INT,
    @score1 INT,
    @score2 INT,
    @totalScore INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @score1 = (SELECT SUM(En_ResultTeamA)
                   FROM Encounter
                   WHERE Te_IdTeamA = @teamId AND Ch_Id = @ch_Id)
    SET @score2 = (SELECT SUM (En_ResultTeamB)
                   FROM Encounter
                   WHERE Te_IdTeamB = @teamId AND Ch_Id = @ch_Id)

    SET @totalScore = @score1 + @score2
END
GO
```

Here the table that the stored procedure is using. It represents an encounter between two teams for a championship (`ch_id`) and a season (`se_id`).

A team, according to HOME or AWAY can be TeamA or TeamB.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Encounter]
(
    [En_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [En_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Te_IdTeamA] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Te_IdTeamB] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Se_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Ch_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [En_ResultTeamA] [int] NULL,
    [En_ResultTeamB] [int] NULL
)
```

So I'm trying to make a view that takes all the Teams playing in a championship from a table 'Affiliate' (this is simple) and add a column 'Score' to this view and for each row, each team, the column 'Score' must show what the SP calculate.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is what I expect to have like view, from the Encounter Table.
ps:Thank You HABO

```
+----------------+--------+------------+
| ChampionshipId | TeamId | TotalScore |
+----------------+--------+------------+
|              1 |      1 |          6 |
|              1 |   5    |          5 |
|              1 |      2 |          4 |
|              1 |      4 |          2 |
|              1 |      3 |          0 |
+----------------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: It would help to see what the view is you are trying to modify. It may be possible to join to this table and get the sum: SELECT SUM(En_ResultTeamA+ En_ResultTeamB) as Total

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Aside: You might want `@totalscore` to be an [`output` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#returning-data-using-an-output-parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
CREATE VIEW Vw_League AS
SELECT Ch_Id,
       Se_Id,
       [Te_IdTeamA] AS TeamId,
       'Home' AS Stadium,
       SUM(En_ResultTeamA) AS Total
  FROM Encounter WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY [Te_IdTeamA],
         Ch_Id,
         Se_Id
UNION ALL
SELECT Ch_Id,
       Se_Id,
       [Te_IdTeamB] AS TeamId,
       'Away' AS Stadium,
       SUM(En_ResultTeamB) AS Total
  FROM Encounter WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY [Te_IdTeamB],
         Ch_Id,
         Se_Id

SELECT * FROM Vw_League
```

Comment: It is really close to what I want :D

I only want the championshipID, the TeamID and HomeTotal. I would like that the SUM, takes every points in season 1 and 2 together. It's for makin the final ranking between teams.
If you can do something like that, I will be greatefull ^^

But thaks, this is pretty cool too, I may use it :)

Comment: You can do that with `SELECT Ch_Id,
    TeamId,
    SUM(Total) AS Total
  FROM Vw_League
 WHERE Stadium = 'Home'
GROUP BY Ch_Id,
   TeamId`

Comment: Thanks Muzaffer, almost what I want too, look to my EDIT part, I gave an example Output for more clarification.

Comment: Simply try removing Stadium condition.`SELECT Ch_Id,
    TeamId,
    SUM(Total) AS Total
  FROM Vw_League
GROUP BY Ch_Id,
   TeamId`